# What does SELECT ~0; do?

Tags: mysql, cast

I've recently stumbled into an interesting Mysql query:

`SELECT ~0;`
results:
`18446744073709551615`

Which is the max value of a bigint unsigned. What does the tilde operator do in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It selects the logical negation of 0 and returns it in the implicitly converted datatype.  Rather than selecting 8 bytes containing all 0's, it selects 8 bytes containing all 1's, returning the maximum possible unsigned value.

Comment: Learn something new every day.